# A better way to create a URL based on window.location.href?

Tags: javascript, url

The code I have right now:

```
    setDomain: function() {
        var currentUrl = window.location.href;
        var uFragment  = currentUrl.split('\n');
        var domain = "";

        if(currentUrl.match(/<removed>/)) {
            domain = uFragment[0] + '//' + uFragment[2] + '/' + uFragment[3] + '/';
        } else {
            domain = uFragment[0] + '//' + uFragment[2] + '/';
        }

        this.domain = domain;
    },
```

This function decides which domain my script should use.  At work, we have internal testing sites that are `subdomain.domain.tld/SiteName` and `subdomain.domain.tld:81/SiteName`

The code splits the current url by / and then appends `http://`, `domain.subdomain.tld`, and `SiteName`

I am looking for another solution because using `uFragment[0]`, while it does what I need, is ugly.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Why changing when it's working :) Maybe with apache rewrite rules, but not that easy to do comparing to what you've done, and for the same result.

Comment: If "uFragment[0]" is the protocol, then just dont include it. If you start the URL with "//", then the protocol of the current page will be used.